# How to set default value for a variable in a parameter list

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want the variable to take a default value when a value not passed to a Table valued function.

Could any one please help me do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A table valued function with default value for a parameter.

```
create function GetValue(@Value int = 1) 
returns table as return 
(
  select @Value as ID
)
```

Use it like this

```
select *
from dbo.GetValue(default)
```

Comment: Note: "When a parameter of the function has a default value, the keyword DEFAULT must be specified when calling the function to get the default value. This behavior is different from parameters with default values in user-defined stored procedures in which omitting the parameter also implies the default value." - [Creating User-Defined Functions (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx)